# Obfuscate an EXPO file

Tags: react-native, expo, android-obfuscation

First time I use Expo (react native app) to deploy an app into Googgle play store. Expo Generates an aab -file that I can upload to the store. But it seems like it is not obfuscated. Reading through the Expo documents I don't get my head around how to define this in my build process.

If I understand documentation correctly it is in my eas.json file I should define this, or have I misunderstood?

But I don't know how the code should look like. Any suggestions for how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Follow this steps**

1. Make sure expo-build-properties is installed, or install it if needed:
   `expo install expo-build-properties`
2. In your `app.json` / `app.config.js` change this dependency:

```js
"plugins": [
      "expo-build-properties"
    ]
```

to

```js
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
```

After these steps, it should be obfuscated.
Source: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/#example-appjson-with-config-plugin

Comment: Hey, concerning iOS do we have to do something similar to hide our bundle code ? I don't know if we can access the Javascript code in an iOS app.

Also I try your answer, but I still can see my constant variable name with his value ... Or is the obfuscation not so strong ?

Comment: @Zerender, magnificent!

Comment: Is there the equivalent for ios?

Answer (score 2):

I found my android app crashed with the recommended change.
I eventually found Github issue https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15761
Paste in the 'plugins' section of app.json as follows:

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true,
        "extraProguardRules": "-keep public class com.horcrux.svg.** {*;}",
        "allowBackup": false
      }
    }
  ]
],
```